# Postgres & JSONB - Levenshtein argument

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have two tables and want to do a left join from the second to the first by way of a Levenshtein fuzzy matching algorithm. The ita_public table contains jsonb data, and the matching takes place between a string (supplier_name) and some nested data within the json string.

> ita_public

```
CREATE TABLE public.ita_public
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('ita_data_id_seq'::regclass),
    info jsonb NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT ita_data_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

> ita_sn_private

CREATE TABLE public.ita_sn_private

```
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('ita_sn_private_id_seq'::regclass),
    supplier_name character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    supplier_streetadd character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT ita_sn_private_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

> Query

```
SELECT 
priv.*,
pub.info::json->>'name' as match_org_name,
pub.info::json->'locations'->'items'-> 0 ->'address'->>'streetName'

FROM ita_sn_private as priv
LEFT JOIN ita_public as pub
ON ((levenshtein(priv.supplier_name, pub.info::json->>'name') < 3))
```

However I'm getting the error :

> ERROR:  levenshtein argument exceeds maximum length of 255 characters
>   SQL state: 22023

Can anyone help with this? I can't find anything on the internet about this. I created test tables and test data, and the query worked fine, but on my original dataset it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/fuzzystrmatch.html#id-1.11.7.24.6):

> levenshtein(text source, text target) returns int
>
> Both source and target can be any non-null string, with a maximum of 255 characters.

You can try:

```
ON ((levenshtein(left(priv.supplier_name, 255), left(pub.info::json->>'name', 255)) < 3))
```